# Angular JS factory and variable access

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently changed my factory **FROM**

```
app.factory('controllerComm', function($rootScope)
{
  var showVforum    = {};
  showVforum.result = false;
  showVforum.prepBroadcast = function(val)
  {
    this.result = val;
    this.broadcastVal();
  }

  showVforum.broadcastVal = function()
  {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('toggleVforum')
  }
  return showVforum;
});
```

To **THIS**

```
app.factory('controllerComm', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
  var showVforum    = {};
  showVforum.result = false;
  showVforum.prepBroadcast = function(val)
  {
    this.result = val;
    this.broadcastVal();
  }

  showVforum.broadcastVal = function()
  {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('toggleVforum')
  }
  return showVforum;
}]);
```

I did this for JS minification reasons. Before I changed it, I had this working in one of my controllers:

```
$scope.$on('toggleVforum', function()
{
  $scope.isVisible = controllerComm.result;
  $('#vforum').verticalAlign();
  player.play();
});
```

`controllerComm.result` is now returning `undefined` since I changed my factory and I cannot figure out why. Any ideas?

**edit**

the error:

```
TypeError: Object function e(e,f,i){var j=c.defer(),k=j.promise,l=y(i)&&!i,f=a.defer(function(){try{j.resolve(e())}catch(a){j.reject(a),d(a)}l||b.$apply()},f),i=function(){delete g[k.$$timeoutId]};
k.$$timeoutId=f;g[f]=j;k.then(i,i);return k} has no method 'prepBroadcast'
    at Object.$scope.hideVforum (http://localhost/aventos/resources/js/aventos.js:645:20)
    at http://localhost/aventos/resources/js/angular.min.js:72:251
    at http://localhost/aventos/resources/js/angular.min.js:144:140
    at Object.e.$eval (http://localhost/aventos/resources/js/angular.min.js:88:347)
    at Object.e.$apply (http://localhost/aventos/resources/js/angular.min.js:88:454)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/aventos/resources/js/angular.min.js:144:122)
    at HTMLButtonElement.x.event.dispatch (http://localhost/aventos/resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:14129)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (http://localhost/aventos/resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:10866)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the result variable with the broadcast.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('toggleVForum',{result: this.result});
```

controllerComm is not defined in the *$on* listener even though you may be injecting it into the controller where the listener is defined.

```
$scope.$on('toggleVForum',function(evt,args){
    $scope.isVisible = args.result;
    ...
});
```

Comment: That did it, I was trying that but I missed the first argument was event. I was doing `$scope.$on('toggleVForum',function(args){` but that explains why it wasn't working. I am running into another issue though. When I call `controllerComm.prepBroadcast(false)` the second time, I get an error saying '..blah blah has no method prepBroadcast`

Comment: Where is the 2nd call being made from?

Comment: Basically I have two controllers, the first calls `controllerComm.prepBroadcast(true)` which toggles a boolean in the second controller. The second controller then calls `controllerComm.prepBroadcast(false)` which toggles it yet again (when the user clicks). I added the error when my second controller calls `controllerComm.prepBroadcast(false)`

Comment: If the service `controllerComm` is being injected into both controllers, then the method `prepBroadcast` should be available.

Comment: `app.controller('AventosController', ['$scope','$http','$q','controllerComm', function ($scope, $http, $q, controllerComm)` & `app.controller('VforumController', ['$scope','$http','$q','$timeout','controllerComm', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, controllerComm)` They definitely both have access to `controllerComm` Is it possibly the way `controllerComm` is defined?

Comment: Your second controller's parameter list is wrong.  You're injecting `$q` but don't add it in the controller's function parameter list.  `controllerComm` is actually receiving `$timeout`'s definition, that's why you see it as a big messy function.

Comment: The first time I call `controllerComm.prepBroadcast()` I logged `controllerComm` and it is a javascript object, the second time I call it, its a huge messy function like the one I posted above in the error

Comment: Ahhhh! That was it. Welp, I feel dumb, thanks again for the help! I owa ya one :D

Comment: Welcome, glad I could help again. :)